# I am getting /'undefined' redirection from my MVC 3 Razor Website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, undefined

I have MVC 3 website. When checked Google Analytics I saw 'undefined' error and I don't know why I am getting that error.
When I visit that page below I am not getting but some how someone getting that redirection to undefined.

How can I define why I am getting that error or is it something with MVC 3?

ORIGINAL WEB PAGE

http://www.emlakrex.com/Sonuc/detay/Merkez,Bursa,Kiralik,Arsa,Arazi,Ilanlari,2000-TL/PrptyID-273163

REDIRECTED WEB PAGE

http://www.emlakrex.com/'undefined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

undefined often comes from javascript. I can only assume that your re-direct is carried out by javascript, or, you have some java script function that attempts to use an undefined variable. Please provide some code samples of where you think this is failing.

Comment: I have found that this often comes about when you've got a JQuery event doing an e.PreventDefault() and then a window.location.href = [something]